# Using variable in multiple partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My application allows users to order supplies. I am using multiple partial views that are rendered on one Index View.  The partial views are broken down to the header information of the order, Form Ordering and Supply Ordering.

In my Index Controller, I create a unique "TransNum" for each order.

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
string str = guid.ToString();
ViewBag.TransNum = str;
```

This "TransNum" is what I will use to tie the actual supplies and forms ordered to the header information of the user.

Currently, I display the TransNum currently in my index view, but I also need to use it in my addsupplies view and

```
<!-- Begin RequisitionNumber-->

<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("RequisitionNumber:", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBox("RequisitionNumber", null, new { @class = "form-control",   Value = ViewBag.TransNum, @readonly = "readonly" })
</div>

<!-- Add partial Views-->
@{Html.RenderAction("DataGrid");} 
@{Html.RenderAction("AddSupplies");} 
@{Html.RenderAction("AddForms");}
```

Is there an easy way to pass (Viewbag.TransNum) into the Index view, and the three partial views as well (DataGrid, AddSupplies, AddForms) ?

I have been researching online and have seen a few things on my own.  I have tried the following:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("AddSupplies", new { ViewBag.TransNum });}
```

But I am still unable to grab the ViewBag.TransNum on the partial view.

I can provide the controller code as well, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by using TempData, which allowed me to store the unique Transaction Number on the index controller and pass it to the other controllers that need it.  Here is a sample:

```
{

//Auto Generate Requisition Number
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
string str = guid.ToString();
ViewBag.TransNum = str;
TempData["ReqNo"] = str;

return View();
}
```

Above, I created my unique ID and stored it as ReqNo in TempData.

Below, I can call that variable very easily in another controller.

```
public ActionResult AddSupplies()
{

var q = db.ICS_Orders;
var z = db.ICS_Indexs.ToList();

ViewBag.TransNum = TempData["ReqNo"];
return View(q);

}
```

There are probably other and/or better ways to accomplish this.  But, this got the job done for me.

Comment: Yes, it is always better to use ViewModels to pass data to your views, instead of using ViewBag and TempData.